# Best way to assign memory for a program

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am currently working on a code, incremental garbage collection which is just a simulation. What i mean is that in the program, the user wil enter the amount of physical memory to be assigned and also will be entering keywords like `x = alloc(10MB)` which expects me to allocate the object "x" 10MB of the physical memory. So i will be needing a start pointer as an end pointer for the code.
My doubt: What would be the best way to assign this "physical memory" ? I came across malloc and calloc where many recommended not to use it unless necessary. Also there is the new operator. So i wanted to know if there was any other better way. And this physical memory will remain fixed through the process.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why alloc(10MB) should allocated 15MB ?

Comment: oh sorry. typo... I made the edits

Comment: @BrownieTuffy you want malloc and free..

Comment: And i need to memset the it to 0 after using malloc.. correct?

Comment: Also is there a way i can make another pointer point to the end address of the block.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, instead of allocating raw memory or even using raw pointers, it's generally encouraged to use the collection classes of the C++ standard library, such as `std::vector`. If you're writing a simulation for garbage collection, I can imagine that you design a class for unified access to GC-managed memory, and then you allocate a vector of them.

If, however, this is not the case, you *can* (although in C++, you reallly shouldn't) use `malloc()`, or `calloc()` if you need zero-initialized memory.

> Also is there a way i can make another pointer point to the end address of the block.?

Sure, use pointer arithmetic.

```
T *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * N_ELEMENTS);
T *endPastOne = ptr + N_ELEMENTS;
```